# Need help making a Capybara test that relies on ActionCable response, pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, capybara, sidekiq, actioncable

I have a page that searches on ElasticSearch, using Sidekiq to perform the search on the background, and ActionCable to let the front-end know when the results are ready. This is working pefectly if you test it manually.

However, my Capybara test is not working

```
Scenario 'posts index page', js: true do

  login user

  visit posts_path(post.slug)

  # Expand the post
  click_link 'Expand'

  expect(page).to have_content("View Gallery")
  logout

end
```

end

But this fails because it never finds the "Expand" link, which is loaded after ActionCable broadcasts the results of the search.

I have set Sidekiq and ES and it's working fine when running the tests . I've checked the logs while the test is run and ActionCable is also broadcasting the results as expected.

I've tested using a "sleep" sentence right before checking for the "Expand" link but that didn't changed the results, so I guess it is not a timing issue and the front-end is missing the broadcast for some reason.

The app is on Rails '~> 5.1' and these are the gems for testing:

[image]

The test is running with apparition driver.

Any ideas of what I could do to fix this? any recommendations (or links!) that could help me solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the apparition master branch

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think I'm using master branch if I have `gem apparition`, right?

Comment: No - that would use the latest released gem.  `gem ‘apparition’, github: ‘twalpole/apparition’` will use the master branch.

Comment: Oh got it. thanks for the clarification. will try that!

Comment: I tried master branch but got the same error